# Order of Evaluation for Fold Expressions

Tags: c++, c++17, fold-expression

Fold expressions seem to be a nice way to apply a function to each element of a tuple. However, if the applied function has side effects, the order of function invocations might be an important concern.

Consider:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename... Ts>
void printStuff(Ts... args)
{
    ( ([](auto&& v) { std::cout << v << " "; })(args), ... );
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    printStuff("hello", 42, 1.5f);
    // expected output: hello 42 1.5
}
```

This [seems to work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a864eaf62f5eab75).

But is the order of evaluation for the lambdas guaranteed here or could I end up with the values being flipped around in the output? Does the answer change if I used a different operator for chaining the commands together?

Comment: You use comma operator, which is sequenced.

Comment: FYI, that fold expression can be re-written as: `([&]{ std::cout << args << " "; }(), ...);`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A right-fold over an operator expands like this: `... (arg0 op (arg1 op arg2))`. So while the parens help, they don't guarantee anything about the order of the individual elements.

Therefore, it's all left up to `op`. And the [comma operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_other#Comma_operator) (which is distinct from commas separating function arguments), even pre-C++17, is a hard sequence point. It ensures left-to-right evaluation with no cross-talk.

If you had instead used `+`, there would be no sequencing guarantees. So it depends on the operator you use. C++17 added a few more operators that have strict sequencing guarantees (`<<`, for example).

Comment: For reference: The proposal that gave us the stricter sequencing guarantees in C++17 is [P0145r3](https://wg21.link/P0145r3). This one also guarantees that overloading the comma operator will not remove the sequencing guarantees.